# NUnit fail to build test - No Tests discovered

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am working on `selenium` web driver project. I was able to built tests in `Test Explorer` and execute.

At once I am getting following errors when rebuilding the solution.

```
Unit Adapter 3.2.0.0: Test discovery starting
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
NUnit Adapter 3.2.0.0: Test discovery starting
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
Attempt to load assembly with unsupported test framework in  C:\..\CustomerTest.exe
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished
Attempt to load assembly with unsupported test framework in  C:\..\LoginTest.exe
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished
Exception NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException, Exception thrown discovering tests in C:\..\CustomerTest.exe
Cannot run tests in process - a 32 bit process is required.
NUnit Adapter 3.2.0.0: Test discovery complete
Exception NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException, Exception thrown discovering tests in C:\..\LoginTest.exe
Cannot run tests in process - a 32 bit process is required.
NUnit Adapter 3.2.0.0: Test discovery complete
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:02.5558095) ==========
```

I have changed the default processor architecture in to `X64`, but issue not resolved.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank  you.

Comment: Could you show us your Conifguration Manager window? Menu -> Build -> Configuration Manager...

Comment: I would suggest, build your assemblies as Any CPU, for me it appears that your test host is configured to X86.

Comment: My configuration manager platform has set up to Any CPU. Sorry I am unable to add screen shot.

Comment: Project --> CustomerTest, Configuration -> Debug, Platform -> Any CPU.

Comment: Any one can tell me why this "Attempt to load assembly with unsupported test framework" message is giving? Is this something to do with Nunit version?

Comment: It might be happened due to the incompatibility version of NUnit and NUnitTestAdapter. Please visit my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056195/unsupported-test-framework-error-in-nunit/38636695#38636695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the same problem like here: [Visual Studio FsUnit test setup - Exception NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636312/visual-studio-fsunit-test-setup-exception-nunit-engine-nunitengineexception) So installing Adapter Version 3.0.10 should solve your problem. At least it did for me.

You can follow the issue on [github](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/181).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked for me as well. I installed VSTestAdapter 3.0.10. Problem resolved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem just today for some odd reason, because I didnt change anything in the meantime and it worked before.

Fixed it by: Project-> [YourProjectName].properties -> Build -> Platform target: "Any CPU" -> Untick "Prefer 32-Bit"

Comment: I tried this method as well. But finally it worked after installing TestAdapter 3.0.10. Thanks.

Comment: Unticking the prefer x32 bit processor solved everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with NUnit 3 Test Adapter (version 3.2.0). I uninstalled it and tried NUnit Test Adapter Version 2.0.0.0. That solved the problem for me.

I used the VS > Tools > Extensions and Updates to install/uninstall the adapter.

My VS project is set to build for Platform x86 and I was using VS Ultimate 2013 Update 5.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my `.NET Core 2.0` project with `NUnit 3.9` in `Visual Studio 2017` and was stuck with this for quite some time. None of the solutions suggested in other related questions worked.

Then I figured out from **[this](http://hermit.no/net-core-setup/)** link that a class library with target `.NET Standard` does not work. The test project has to target `.NET Core`. Also, `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` NuGet is required.

So, the steps are

1. Make sure that the test project targets `.NET Core`
2. Install latest `NUnit` NuGet (I used 3.9)
3. Install corresponding `NUnitAdapter` NuGet (I used NUnit3Adapter)
4. Install `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` NuGet

Re-build and your tests will appear in **Test Explorer** in Visual Studio.